# How to resolve webpackwarning 'Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload'?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack-dev-server

I am running my reactjs app with webpack and gulp, this is a fragement of my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task("webpack-dev-server", function(callback) {
    // modify some webpack config options
    var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
    myConfig.devtool = "eval";
    myConfig.debug = true;

    // Start a webpack-dev-server
    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
        //publicPath: "/" + myConfig.output.publicPath,
        inline: 'true',
        stats: {
            colors: true
        },
        hot:true,

    }).listen(9090, "localhost", function(err) {
        if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
        gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", "http://localhost:9090/webpack-dev-server/index.html");
    });
});
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["./app/app.js",
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/js",
        filename: "http://localhost:9090/dist/js/myapp.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "myapp.map"
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    }
}
```

When the page reloads chrome devtools show the following error:

```
bootstrap 04b58fb…:25 GET http://localhost:9090/dist/04b58fb8512c7a3f39f8.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)hotDownloadManifest @ bootstrap 04b58fb…:25hotCheck @ bootstrap 04b58fb…:244check @ only-dev-server.js:12(anonymous function) @ only-dev-server.js:70
only-dev-server.js:27 [HMR] Cannot find update. Need to do a full reload!
only-dev-server.js:28 [HMR] (Probably because of restarting the webpack-dev-server)
```

How can I fix this so I can reload the page?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried that:

```
if (module.hot) 
    module.hot.accept();
```

The webpack does not update any modules itself, you have to accept it.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html#what-is-needed-to-use-it

Comment: Just a code snippet without a proper guidance of how and where to use it, is useless.